# (drag) events not working properly

Tags: angular

I am using Angular's default `(drag)` to handle the dropping of a file.

When a user drags over the rectangle, I am trying to add a class. But this class is being added and removed over and over. What am I doing wrong?

For example:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<div class="upload-container" 
     [class.isDraggingOver]="isDraggingOver"
     (drop)="onDrop($event, dropData); isDraggingOver = false"
     (dragover)="isDraggingOver = true; allowDrop($event)"
     (dragenter)="isDraggingOver = true"
     (dragleave)="isDraggingOver = false">
    Stuff in here...
</div>

onDrop(event, data) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    // ...
}

allowDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

I just want to add the class `isDraggingOver` when a hover is active, and remove it when not. I don't know why it's flicking back and forth while I am hovered.

Comment: Can you please provide runnable plunker that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of the same problem. The solution I found, and that's been used in all the examples I've seen so far, is not to use the `dragenter` event, only the `dragover` one. I'm still not sure why it doesn't work with that event, and even if it seems wrong to use the other, that was how I could made it work.